# In Reactjs material-table when scrolling vertically, action icons and selection box are going through the header, overlapping the header

Tags: reactjs, scrollbar, material-table

I am using material-table in reactjs project. when I'm scrolling vertically, action icons and selection box are going through the header. actually it is overlapping the header and the scrollbar is starting from the top of the table, but i wwant to it to start from the below of the header.

```
                 <MaterialTable
                    tableRef={tableRef}
                    title=""
                    onSelectionChange={(rows) => {
                        handleClick(rows);
                    }}
                    columns={headerData}
                    data={leadsDetails.data}   
                    
                    actions={[
                        {
                            icon: () => <PeopleAltIcon style={{ fontSize:"large", color: "#0096A2" }}/>,
                            tooltip: 'Assign',
                            position: 'row',
                            onClick: (event, rowData) => {

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            icon: () => <DeleteIcon style={{ fontSize:"large", color: "#0096A2" }}/>,
                            tooltip: 'Delete',
                            position: 'row',
                            onClick: (event, rowData) => {
                                setConfirmDialog({
                                    isOpen:true,
                                    title:"Are you sure to delete this record ?",
                                    subTitle:"",
                                    onConfirm:() =>{onDeleteIcon(event, rowData)}
                                })
                                
                            }
                            
                            
                        },
                    ]}

                    options={{                            
                        sorting: {sorting}, search: true,
                        paging: true, pageSizeOptions: [10,20,30], pageSize: 10,
                        exportButton: true,
                        //grouping: true, columnsButton: true,
                        headerStyle: { background: "#0096A2", color: "#fff", fontSize: "0.85rem", position:'sticky', top:0,  whiteSpace:"nowrap", height: 20, maxHeight:20 },
                        rowStyle: { color: "#0096A2", fontSize: "0.8rem", padding: 0,height: 20, whiteSpace:"nowrap", maxHeight:20},
                        showTitle: false,
                        toolbar: false,
                        selection: true,
                        maxBodyHeight: '60vh',
                        draggable: false,
                        thirdSortClick: false
                        // tableLayout: "auto"
                    }}
                    isLoading={isLoading}
                />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLJCY.jpg)

Comment: can u please create a codesandbox with ur code?

Comment: did u try overriding the header component where u specify the width of the header? and did u try applying a z-index to the header styling?